# Jquery UI Draggable Scroll Issue in iframe

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I was trying to make a answer draggable in my web page with auto scroll ability.
But for some reason my scroll is not working. it is placed inside a iframe.
I took reference from JqueryUI but was not able to find the appropriate answer.

also sometime it works outside this webpage somewhere else in the project.

Below is my draggable jquery.

```
    var draggableAnswers = machingQuestionElement.find(".answer");
    draggableAnswers.draggable({ revert: "invalid", handle: draggableAnswers.find(".Answerhandle"), axis: 'y', containment: "document" });
    var dropboxes = machingQuestionElement.find(".answerDropbox");
    dropboxes.droppable({ accept: draggableAnswers,
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
            var droppedAnswer = ui.draggable;
            var currentDroppbox = $(this);

            currentDroppbox.height(droppedAnswer.find('.AnswerText').height());
            droppedAnswer.height(droppedAnswer.find('.AnswerText').height());
            //Previous box 
            var previousDropbox = droppedAnswer.parent(".answerDropbox");
            previousDropbox.droppable("option", "disabled", false);
            previousDropbox.find(".placeholder").show();
            $(droppedAnswer).detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).appendTo(currentDroppbox);
            var currentSubQuestion = currentDroppbox.closest(".subQuestion");
            machingQuestionElement.find("input[value=" + droppedAnswer.attr("id") + "]").prop('checked', false);
            var inputDroppedAnswer = currentSubQuestion.find("input[value=" + droppedAnswer.attr("id") + "]")
            inputDroppedAnswer.prop('checked', true);
            if (inputDroppedAnswer.attr("speciality") == "true")
                droppedAnswer.addClass("correctAnswer");
            else
                droppedAnswer.removeClass("correctAnswer");
            currentDroppbox.droppable("option", "disabled", true);
            currentDroppbox.find(".placeholder").hide();
        },
        over: function (event, elem) {
            $(this).addClass("over");
        },
        out: function (event, elem) {
            $(this).removeClass("over");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Buddy i was going to just put draggable query but for more understanding i have done so.

Comment: This is not a MCVE since I can not just run the code and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ll keep this thing in mind next time.

Comment: can you respond to to my question ?